# jQuery -- Why is only the very first condition ever executed or none at all if the first condition is false?

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I'm attempting to do is have a fixed button which, once clicked, scrolls to a particular section on the page. However, only the very first condition is ever executed, and the other conditions are seemingly ignored altogether, even if the first condition is false. What am I doing wrong here? Below is the code.

```
    function scroll() {

        var dob = $('#dob');

        var one = $('#one');
        var two = $('#two');
        var thr = $('#thr');
        var fou = $('#fou');
        var fiv = $('#fiv');

        var scr = $(window).scrollTop();
        var win = $(window).height();

        dob.click(function(){

            if ( scr < win ) {
                    $('html, body').delay(125).animate({
                        'scrollTop' : two.offset().top
                    });
            }

            else if ( scr >= win && scr < (win * 2) ) {
                    $('html, body').delay(125).animate({
                        'scrollTop' : thr.offset().top
                    });
            }

            else if ( scr >= win * 2 && scr < (win * 3) ) {
                    $('html, body').delay(125).animate({
                        'scrollTop' : fou.offset().top
                    });
            }

            else if ( scr >= win * 3 && scr < (win * 4) ) {
                    $('html, body').delay(125).animate({
                        'scrollTop' : fiv.offset().top
                    });
            };

        });

    };

    $(document).ready(function(){scroll();});
```

Comment: You should detect the other conditions, they might be false as well. Log the values and condition results, add a final `else` ... basic debugging.

Comment: What do you mean? If the first condition is true, the corresponding code executes. If the first condition is false--at least to my knowledge--it should then move on to determine whether the second block of code is true or false. @Teemu

Comment: Also, looks like there are some missing parenthesis/brackets in your code.

Comment: Where abouts? It's working fine now? @showdev

Comment: They were fixed in Nikolay Ermakov's code.

Comment: I still have no clue what you're talking about. The only difference between his code and mine is the placement of the `scr` and `win` variables and the slight refinement of the conditions... @showdev

Comment: It doesn't seem to matter now that your code working. But in your original code, the `click()` handler is missing its closing `)` and the `scroll()` function is missing its closing `}`.

Comment: Oh yeah, you're right! I must've accidentally deleted that part of my code while formatting my question on here. I'll be sure to edit that in case somebody wants to use this as a reference at a later date. Thanks for pointing that out. @showdev

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because values for `scr` and `win` are set only once when your `scroll` function is run on document ready. You probably want to refresh them each time the `click` is called.

So the correct version would go as:

```
function scroll() {
    var dob = $('#dob');
    var one = $('#one');
    var two = $('#two');
    var thr = $('#thr');
    var fou = $('#fou');
    var fiv = $('#fiv');
}


dob.click(function() {
    var scr = $(window).scrollTop();
    var win = $(window).height();

    if (scr < win) {
        $('html, body').delay(125).animate({
            'scrollTop': two.offset().top
        });
    } else if (scr < (win * 2)) {
        $('html, body').delay(125).animate({
            'scrollTop': thr.offset().top
        });
    } else if (scr < (win * 3)) {
        $('html, body').delay(125).animate({
            'scrollTop': fou.offset().top
        });
    } else if (scr < (win * 4)) {
        $('html, body').delay(125).animate({
            'scrollTop': fiv.offset().top
        });
    };

});

$(document).ready(function() {
    scroll();
});
```

Comment: It's exactly this. The functions are all mixed up.

Comment: I might be missing something, but wouldn't you want to add the `scr` and `win` updates at the beginning of the handler?

Comment: You are right, thanks! It would work either way, keeping them inside is surely better.

Comment: One minor nitpick: all of the >= tests are redundant: after you've already gotten to the else of  `if(scr < foo)`, there's no need to check for `(scr >= foo)`; it's guaranteed to be true.

Comment: It's unnecessary because it's sequential, right?! @DanielBeck

Comment: @user2230470 yep, exactly.  Not that it was *wrong* the other way, this is just a bit more readable  (and less risk of accidentally leaving gaps uncovered between the various else clauses)

Comment: What do you mean by "less risk of accidentally leaving gaps uncovered between the various else clauses"? @DanielBeck

Comment: @user2230470 I mean this sort of thing:  `if (foo < 10) {...} else if (foo >= 12 && foo < 15) {...}` Especially when maintaining old code, it's an easy mistake to update one clause and forget to change the another, leaving gaps that aren't included in any clause.  With `if (foo < 10) {...} else if (foo < 15) {...}` there are just fewer opportunities to goof up.

Answer (score 0):

You have your functions mixed up. You want all the scroll stuff to be in a function, and then bind the click handler to that function, as well as initializing it on document.ready:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    scroll();
    var dob = $('#dob');

    dob.click(function(){
        scroll();
    }
});

function scroll() {
    var one = $('#one');
    var two = $('#two');
    var thr = $('#thr');
    var fou = $('#fou');
    var fiv = $('#fiv');

    var scr = $(window).scrollTop();
    var win = $(window).height();

    if ( scr < win ) {
        $('html, body').delay(125).animate({
            'scrollTop' : two.offset().top
        });
    }
    else if ( scr >= win && scr < (win * 2) ) {                 
        $('html, body').delay(125).animate({
            'scrollTop' : thr.offset().top
        });
    }
    else if ( scr >= win * 2 && scr < (win * 3) ) {
        $('html, body').delay(125).animate({
            'scrollTop' : fou.offset().top
        });
    }
    else if ( scr >= win * 3 && scr < (win * 4) ) {
        $('html, body').delay(125).animate({
            'scrollTop' : fiv.offset().top
        });
    };
}
```

Comment: Hm... that seems pretty redundant and it's fine the way I have it. If you're interested, though; the solution was to move the `var scr` and `var win` inside the `dob.click(function()...` so that the variables are returned not just when the document loads, but whenever the button is clicked.

Comment: No, using the scroll function to initialize the state of the site outside of the document.ready function is redundant. Moving it to a function allows you to call it when you need it, and bind it to other click events on the fly.